# Native linking failed _sqlite3 when debugging iOS device

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm getting a series of compile errors (see screenshot) when trying to compile or deploy to device. If I try to compile using the `IPhoneSimulator` then everything works fine.

[Here is a screenshot of the errors.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/havOh.png)

I am stuck with this at the moment and need to be actually able to deploy to my iPhone device and test my app there. Since linking is failing with `sqlite`, I'd be surprised if there's no solution for it yet.

Any tips or advice on how to solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: For reference:Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_bind_int64. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. Desiree.iOS   
Error  Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _sqlite3_data_count. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in. Desiree.iOS

Comment: Found a temporary workaround by setting an mtouch parameter -dlsym=yes.   See https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42372 for reference.  I am still not marking the question as resolved to see if there's a better option out there...